# get all (derived) interfaces of a class

Tags: java, reflection

`java.lang.Class.getInterfaces` returns all directly implemented interfaces ie doesn't walk the class tree to get all interfaces of all parent types. eg For example the hierarchy

```
public interface A {}
public interface B {}
public interface C extends B {}

public class Foo implements A {} // Foo.class.getInterfaces() returns [A]
public class Bar implements C {} // Bar.class.getInterfaces() returns [C], note B is not included.
```

For `Bar` I would like to get `[B, C]`, but for any arbitrary tree depth.

I could write this myself, but I'm sure a library must exist that does this already, any ideas?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang) has method you need: [`ClassUtils.getAllInterfaces`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ClassUtils.html#getAllInterfaces%28java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: Much obliged, this is exactly what I was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

#### Guava Solution:

```
final Set<TypeToken> tt = TypeToken.of(cls).getTypes().interfaces();
```

This is a much more powerful and cleaner reflection API than the ancient Apache stuff.

Comment: +1 I was looking to get all interfaces so I could use the built in [newProxyInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance-java.lang.ClassLoader-java.lang.Class:A-java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler-) method and guava had a different method for creating dynamic proxies that was much more simple: 'Reflection.newProxy'. See [Reflection Explained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained)

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget, **Spring Framework** has many similar util classes like Apache Commons Lang. So there is: `org.springframework.util.ClassUtils#getAllInterfaces`

Comment: Isn't it return directly implemented interfaces?

Answer (score 2):

```
public Stream<Class<?>> getInterfaces(Class<?> type) {
    return Stream.of(type.getInterfaces())
                 .flatMap(interfaceType -> Stream.concat(Stream.of(interfaceType), getInterfaces(interfaceType)));
}
```

Comment: Answer should go on top. Very clean!

Comment: You should use Set instead of List, in order to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: Probably best to just return Stream so caller can decide whether uniqueness or ordering or whatever is important.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface A {}

public interface B {}

public interface E extends B{ }

public class C implements A{}

public class D extends C implements E{}
```

[image]

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final List<Class<?>> result = getAllInterfaces(D.class);            
        for (Class<?> clazz : result) {
            System.out.println(clazz);
        }
    }

    public static List<Class<?>> getAllInterfaces(Class<?> clazz) {
        if (clazz == null) {
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>> Log : null argument ");
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        List<Class<?>> interfacesFound = new ArrayList<>();
        getAllInterfaces(clazz, interfacesFound);
        return interfacesFound;
    }

    private static void getAllInterfaces(Class<?> clazz,
                                         List<Class<?>> interfacesFound) {
        while (clazz != null) {
            Class<?>[] interfaces = clazz.getInterfaces();

            for (int i = 0; i < interfaces.length; i++) {
                if (!interfacesFound.contains(interfaces[i])) {
                    interfacesFound.add(interfaces[i]);
                    getAllInterfaces(interfaces[i], interfacesFound);
                }
            }
            clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
        }
    }
}
```