# How to get the original class from anonymous class? Java

Tags: java, reflection

I can't figure out how to get the original abstract class or interface where an anonymous inner class is defined.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object obj = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
    };

    System.out.println(obj.getClass());
    System.out.println(obj.getClass().getSuperclass()); //Works for abstract classes only
}
```

Output:

```
class my.package.MyClass$1
class java.lang.Object
```

How can I get the original class? (`Runnable.class` in this case)

Comment: maybe `obj.getInterfaces()`... but you could include why you want to know it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the help! No one really answered my question fully, so I decided to combine the different answers to get this comprehensive solution.

```
public static Class<?> getOriginalClass(Object obj) {
    Class<?> cls = obj.getClass();
    if (cls.isAnonymousClass()) {
        return cls.getInterfaces().length == 0 ? cls.getSuperclass() : cls.getInterfaces()[0];
    } else {
        return cls;
    }
}
```

Shortened:

```
public static Class<?> getOriginalClass(Object obj) {
    Class<?> cls = obj.getClass();
    return cls.isAnonymousClass()
            ? cls.getInterfaces().length == 0 ? cls.getSuperclass() : cls.getInterfaces()[0]
            : cls;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is correct to get the superclass. But Runnable is an interface that's why it isn't working.
Check this answer on how to get all interfaces: [Get all interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616055/get-all-derived-interfaces-of-a-class)

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned runnable is an interface, so you can't use the getClass method to get its name. You can however do this:

```
System.out.println(obj.getClass().getInterfaces()[0].getName())
```

Notice getInterfaces returns an array so if you were implementing more than one you'd have to loop through it with a for loop.