# Adding custom annotation to repository interface in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-data-mongodb

I have a problem with detecting custom annotation. When i try to check it by reflection it doesn't show up. Is spring omitting all annotations on repository interface when he creating an instance? I was testing it with normal class and searching method found that custom annotation.

```
Spring-boot-2.7.4
Java 11
```

MyAnnotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface Encrypted {}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface SubscriptionRepository extends MongoRepository<Subscription, String> {
    boolean existsByEmail(@Encrypted String s);
}
```

AndSearching

```
@Configuration
class EncryptionConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    SubscriptionRepository subscriptionRepository;
    
    @PostConstruct
    void method() {
        Method[] methods = subscriptionRepository.getClass().getMethods();

        for (Method method : methods) {
            Annotation[][] annotationTab = method.getParameterAnnotations();
            for (Annotation[] annotationRow : annotationTab) {
                for (Annotation annotation : annotationRow) {
                    Encrypted encrypted = (Encrypted) annotation;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Probably because spring (+ -data-mongo!) "sub-classes"/proxies/stubs these ("interface beans") at runtime!?

Comment: So ["java get all interfaces"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6616055/592355) could bring you further..?

Comment: Et [voila, the spring-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45170639/592355) 

Comment: Thanks xerx593 that should solve my problem :D