# can proxy some classes but not others

Tags: java, reflection

***UPDATE*** solution is [Java.lang.reflect.Proxy returning another proxy from invocation results in ClassCastException on assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642700/java-lang-reflect-proxy-returning-another-proxy-from-invocation-results-in-class/2643243#2643243)

My test code proxies `java.sql.Connection`.

I create my proxy like so:

```
log.info("connection is "+connection.getClass().getName()+", "+
    (connection instanceof Connection));
Object proxy = java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
    connection.getClass().getClassLoader(),
    connection.getClass().getInterfaces(),
    new MockFailureWrapper(connection));
log.info("proxy is "+proxy.getClass().getName()+", "+
    (proxy instanceof Connection));
return (Connection)proxy;
```

When I wrap an H2 DB connection, this works perfectly.

When I try and wrap a MySQL connection, the cast of the proxy to `Connection` in the return fails, even though the `connection` I'm wrapping is of type `Connection`.  The exception is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy11 cannot be cast to java.sql.Connection
```

The log line for an H2 connection is:

```
connection is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection, true
proxy is $Proxy9, true
```

And for the MySQL connection:

```
connection is com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection, true
proxy is $Proxy11, false
```

**What's going on, and why can't I wrap MySQL DB connections**?

Comment: Show us the `Exception`/`Error` you get please.

Comment: @AdamArold classic CastCastException; added it to the question

Comment: What do you see if you debug your code at the return statement? What type does `proxy` have?

Comment: @AdamArold proxy is an anonymous class of some sort, created dynamically by Java's reflection; I've printed tried to clarify in the logging in the question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java.lang.reflect.Proxy returning another proxy from invocation results in ClassCastException on assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642700/java-lang-reflect-proxy-returning-another-proxy-from-invocation-results-in-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
connection.getClass().getInterfaces()
```

It just gives you the interfaces that are directly implemented by the class you would like to proxy. If the Connection-interface is implemented f.eg. by a superclass of the MySql-Connection class (lets say AbstractConnection), your proxy will not implement the Connection interface.

To fix this, add the Connection-Interface to the array of interfaces your proxy should implement.